# Is it possible to tween scroll position of ScrollPane component with TweenLite?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, gsap

In actionscript3, using the ScrollPane component and the TweenLite package, would it be possible to animate to a particular scroll position?  This seems like it should be possible, but I'm not sure exactly how to go about it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out, so I thought I should go ahead and post the solution.  It is indeed possible to use TweenLite to animate to a scroll position on a ScrollPane component.

You just need to do:

```
TweenLite.to(yourScrollPane, 1, {verticalScrollPosition: yourScrollPane.verticalScrollPosition+amountToScroll});
```

Answer (score 1):

[Tweenlite](http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/) also provides a scrollRect Plugin.

You have to scoll down to the plugin Examples and there you have to scroll again.

Their example:

```
import com.greensock.*; 
import com.greensock.easing.*;

TweenLite.to(mc, 1, {scrollRect:{left:0, right:288, top:0, bottom:216}});
```

Be careful with the parentheses after the `scrollRect` attribute. The first time I overlooked it.